# Green's function in 2D

Tags: partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

How does one compute the Green's function of the laplacian on $ \mathbb{R}^2 $? Can someone point me to a reference? In particular, the fourier transform:
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{i m x} e^{i m y}}{m^2+n^2}
$$
does not converge. Is there some standard way to regulate this?

Answer (score 9):

The integral diverges for a good reason: $\mathbb R^2$ does not have Green's function. In potential-theory-speak, $\mathbb R^2$ is not a *Greenian domain*. More precisely, a domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ is Greenian if and only if its complement has positive logarithmic capacity. This is discussed in all potential theory books, such as [Armitage-Gardiner](http://books.google.com/books?id=02p9FQ41o9cC).

The closest thing to Green's function for the plane is $\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which inverts the Laplacian but does not have zero boundary values (or constant sign).

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.